# Redirect from current page to a new page

Tags: ruby, forms, redirect, cgi

I am having trouble with some Ruby CGI.

I have a home page (`index.cgi`) which is a mix of HTML and Ruby, and has a login form in it.

On clicking on the Submit button the POST's action is the same page (`index.cgi`), at which point I check to make sure the user has entered data into the correct fields.

I have a counter which increases by 1 each time a field is left empty.  If this counter is 0 I want to change the current loaded page to something like contents.html.

With this I have:

```
if ( errorCount > 0 )
  do nothing
else
  ....
end
```

What do I need to put where I have the ....?

---

Unfortunately I cannot use any frameworks as this is for University coursework, so have to use base Ruby.

As for using the CGI#header method as you have suggested, I have tried using this however it is not working for me.

As mentioned my page is index.cgi.  This is made of a mixture of Ruby and HTML using "here doc" statements.

At the top of my code page I have my shebang line, following by a HTML header statement.

I then do the CGI form validation part, and within this I have tried doing something like: print this.cgi( { 'Status' => '302 Moved', 'location' =>
'{http://localhost:10000/contents.html' } )

All that happens is that this line is printed at the top of the browser window, above my index.cgi page.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Without seeing the source code our ability to help you is limited.

Comment: You must send the headers before any other output, otherwise CGI will create the default headers for you. I updated my answer with a link to a very simple example.

Comment: Gioele, Many thanks for your help.  I made the silly mistake of putting " puts "Content-Type: text/html\n\n" " at the top of my file.  I have now moved it below my form validation script (which has the redirect statement) and it works.

Answer (score 1):

To redirect the browser to another URL you must output an 30X HTTP response that contains the `Location: /foo/bar` header. You can do that using the [`CGI#header`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-i-header) method.

Instead of dealing with these details that you do not yet master, I suggest you use a simple framework as [Sinatra](http://sinatrarb.com) or, at least, write your script as a [Rack](http://rack.rubyforge.org)-compatible application.

If you really need to use the bare CGI class, have a look at this simple example: https://github.com/tdtds/amazon-auth-proxy/blob/master/amazon-auth-proxy.cgi.

Comment: The OP updated his question with some more information in response to your answer.

Comment: I tried on several occasions to do this using the "Add Comment" box yesterday, however it did not work.

Comment: New users cannot comment until they gain some reputation points. However, you can and should accept the use the "accept" button on the answer that helped you solve your problem ;)